# Difference in a way of writing a void function return

Tags: c++, return, void

Here's a code snippet I found [here](https://github.com/mkeeter/antimony/blob/develop/src/app/app.cpp#L135)

```
void App::onSave()
{
    if (filename.isEmpty())
        return onSaveAs();

//do saving here
}

void App::onSaveAs()
{
    QString f = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(NULL, "Save as", "", "*.sb");
    if (!f.isEmpty())
    {

//filename generation

        return onSave();
    }
}
```

My question is: is there any difference between `return onSave();` , as it is written here, and something like this:

```
onSave();
return;
```

It confused me because the functions are of **void** type and don't return anything.

Comment: Hm, looks like that's valid. I didn't know! Thanks for teaching me something new.

Comment: @MrLister No problem! ;)  Neither did I, actually. That's what makes me so surprised.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ standard says:

> A return statement with an expression of type void can be used only in functions with a return type of cv void; the expression is evaluated just before the function returns to its caller.

So the two forms are equivalent in C++.

Note that the C standard says:

> A return statement with an expression shall not appear in a function whose return type is void

The relaxation of this restriction in C++ probably has to do with templates.

Answer (score 1):

You asked:

> is there any difference between
>
> ```
> return onSave();
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> onSave();
> return;
> ```

There is no difference between the two.

Comment: Both compile to the same binaries, on any optimisation level? OK.

Comment: @Lister, I don't have a definite answer to that. I'll be very surprised if there any performance differences between the two.